# Can I make a portion of my code not active in processing?

Tags: processing

I am trying to make stars in a night sky. The problem is that for some reason, when the stars keep flashing endlessly and wont stay where they are. Right now, my code looks like this:

```
float r1 = 14;
float r2 = 59;
float g1 = 4;
float g2 = 136;
float b1 = 77;
float b2 = 237;
int smX = 350;
int smY = 310;
void setup() {
  size(500, 600);
  smooth();
  noStroke();
}
void draw () {

  //sky&background stuff
  for(float i = 0; i <= 600; i++) {
   float r = lerp(r1, r2, i/600);
   float g = lerp(g1, g2, i/600);
   float b = lerp(b1, b2, i/600);
   stroke(r, g, b);
   line(0, i, width, i);
 }

   for (int s = 0; s < 40; s++) {
   stroke(255);
   float starX = random(0, 500);
   float starY = random(0, 600);
   if (s < 40) {
   line(starX, starY,starX, starY);
   }
}
}
```

Ideally, after the stars appear, Id like them to stay where they are. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of recalculating new random values every time draw() is called, can you calculate the random values just once, inside setup(), and then store them into a couple of arrays, and just have draw() draw stars using the values from the array?  That way the stars' positions would be the same every time draw() is called.

Comment: This will work, but really this is exactly what the noLoop method is for.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add the [noLoop](https://processing.org/reference/noLoop_.html) function to the end of your setup method.

```
void setup() {
 //rest of your code
 noLoop();
}
```

This stops Processing from continuously executing the code within `draw()`.